# Differentiation using l´Hopital

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I need to use L´Hopital's rule with this functions:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan(x))^{\tan(2x)}$$

I take the exponent down using the properties of logarithms and then make the denominator like: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{1}{\ln(1-\sin(x))}}$ but I still get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(x)\ln(1-\sin(x))\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(1-\sin(x))}{1/\cos(x)}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\frac{-\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^3(x)}{(\sin(x)-1)\sin(x)}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^3(x)}{\sin(x)-1}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}-3\cos(x)\sin(x)\bigg)\\
&=e^0\\
&=1
\end{align}$$
 I can tell you the answer for the second limit is $1/e$, but the technique is pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks! I have one question, how did you go from $((sin(x)-1)sin(x))$ to $sin(x)-1$. Which identity did you use?

Comment: @JJAbrams That's quite obvious. $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$

Answer (score 5):

For the first one we have

$$(1-\sin x)^{\cos x}= (1-\sin x)^{\cos x}\frac{(1+\sin x)^{\cos x}}{(1+\sin x)^{\cos x}}=\frac{(\cos^2 x)^{\cos x}}{(1+\sin x)^{\cos x}}\to \frac 11=1$$

indeed by standard limits

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos^2 x)^{\cos x}=\lim_{t\to 0}(t^2)^t=1$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1+\sin x)^{\cos x}=2^0=1$

For the second one

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan x)^{\tan(2x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} \left[(1+(\tan x-1))^\frac{1}{\tan x-1}\right]^{\tan(2x)(\tan x-1)}\to e^{-1}=\frac1e$$

indeed by standard limits

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (1+(\tan x-1))^\frac{1}{\tan x-1}\to e$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \tan(2x)(\tan x-1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}(\tan x-1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{-2\tan x}{1+\tan x}=-1$

Comment: Nicely done. But the OP says "I need to use L'Hopital's rule ..."

Comment: @trancelocation If one want, it suffices use l’Hopital instead of the indicated standard limits. Of course in some particular cases it is very useful and it is important from the theoretical point of view. But I really think that use l'Hopital when it is not needed is not a good way to solve and learn limits on an effective way. For that, reason, when possible, I avoid to use it.

Comment: dito. :-) ........

Answer (score 3):

Without using L'Hospital:
$$\begin{align}1) \ \lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}\cdot 1=\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1+\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}=\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin^2(x))^{\cos(x)}=\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos^2(x))^{\cos(x)}\stackrel{(1)}=\\
&=1.\\
2) \ \lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan(x))^{\tan(2x)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (1+\tan(x)-1)^{\frac{2\tan(x)}{(1-\tan x)(1+\tan x)}}=\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (1+\tan(x)-1)^{-\frac{1}{\tan x-1}}\stackrel{(2)}=\\
&=e^{-1}.\end{align}$$
Note: 
$$\begin{align}\lim_\limits{x\to 0} x^x&=1 \quad (1)\\
\lim_\limits{x\to 0} (1+x)^{1/x}&=e \quad (2) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on the second and a remark on the first limit:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan(x))^{\tan(2x)}$: 
So, consider 
\begin{eqnarray*} \tan(2x)\ln(\tan x)
& \stackrel{\tan(2x)= \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}}{=} & 2\frac{\tan x\cdot \ln(\tan x)}{1-\tan^2x}\\
& \stackrel{t = \tan x, t\to1}{=} & 2\frac{t \ln t}{1-t^2} \\
& \stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim} & 2\frac{\ln t + 1}{-2t}\\
& \stackrel{t\to 1}{\longrightarrow} & -1
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\boxed{\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan(x))^{\tan(2x)} = e^{-1}}$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)}$:

I recommend just to consider the logarithmic limit and not to write all time $e^{\lim ...}$. This is tedious and not necessary:

\begin{eqnarray*} \cos x \ln(1-\sin x)
& = & \frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{\frac{1}{\cos x}}\\
& \stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim} & -\frac{\frac{\cos}{1- \sin x}}{-\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}}\\
& = & \frac{\cos^3 x}{\sin x (1-\sin x)} \\
& = & \frac{\cos x (1-\sin^2 x)}{\sin x (1-\sin x)} \\
& \stackrel{\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{1-\sin x} = 1+\sin x}{=} & \frac{\cos x (1+\sin x)}{\sin x}\\
& \stackrel{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}{\longrightarrow} & 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, $\boxed{\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin(x))^{\cos(x)} = e^0 = 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1-\sin{x})^{\cos{x}}=e^{\cos{x}\log{(1-\sin{x})}}$$

$$\cos{x}\log{(1-\sin{x})}$$

$\cos{x} =\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}$

So it suffices to find the limit $(\sqrt{1-\sin{x}})\log{(1-\sin{x})}$

Take $y=\sqrt{{1-\sin{x}}}$ so $y \to 0$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$

Thus $y\log{y^2} \to^{y \to 0} 0$ using L'Hospital's rule

and also $\sqrt{{1+\sin{x}}} \to \sqrt2$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$

So you can find the first limit.